# PHP AES-128-CTR has different output than GoLang and NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js, go, encryption, openssl

Can't figure out how does PHP openssl_encrypt work, and cannot reproduce its output in GoLang and NodeJs, here's a simplified code in PHP - outputs `hvAB`:

```
<?php
$string = 'aaa';
$cipher = "AES-128-CTR";
$options = 0;
$encryption_iv = '1234567890123456';
$encryption_key = 'bc7316929fe1545bf0b98d114ee3ecb8';
$encryption = openssl_encrypt($string, $cipher, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);
echo $encryption; // hvAB
```

In GoLang, assuming key must be hex decoded to get the desired length of 16 so that AES 128 will be used - outputs `PQ5k`:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    plainText := "aaa"
    fmt.Println(encryption(plainText)) // PQ5k
}

func encryption(plainText string) string {
    bytes := []byte(plainText)
    blockCipher := createCipher()
    stream := cipher.NewCTR(blockCipher, []byte("1234567890123456"))
    stream.XORKeyStream(bytes, bytes)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytes)
}

func createCipher() cipher.Block {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString("bc7316929fe1545bf0b98d114ee3ecb8")
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return block
}
```

And in NodeJs - outputs `PQ5k`:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var algorithm = 'aes-128-ctr';

function encrypt(text, password) {
  const key = Buffer.from(password, "hex").slice(0, 16);
  const ivBuffer = Buffer.from("1234567890123456");
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, ivBuffer);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64') +  cipher.final('base64')
  console.log(encrypted) // PQ5k
}

encrypt('aaa', 'bc7316929fe1545bf0b98d114ee3ecb8');
```

Thought it's an encoding issue at first, but I think that's correct - `openssl_encrypt` will return base64 value. I need to translate the PHP variant into GoLang, but an example in (almost) any other language will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PHP code, the key is not hex decoded, but is a binary string that is 32 bytes in size and thus too large for AES-128.

PHP/OpenSSL implicitly truncates the key by considering only the first 16 bytes.

In Go simply use `key := []byte("bc7316929fe1545b")`

In NodeJS: `const key = Buffer.from("bc7316929fe1545b", "utf8")` to get the PHP result.

Conversely, in the PHP code the key can also be hex decoded using `hex2bin()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here c/c++ version, but output is not yet the same with golang/nodejs.

```cpp
       #include <openssl/aes.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <string.h>
    
       int main() {
        AES_KEY aes_key;
        unsigned char key[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0xbc, 0x73, 0x16, 0x92, 0x9f, 0xe1, 0x54, 0x5b, 0xf0, 0xb9, 0x8d, 0x11, 0x4e, 0xe3, 0xec, 0xb8 }; 
        unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]  = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
        unsigned char ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]; memset( ecount, 0, 16 );
        unsigned int num = 0 ; 
        const  char *x = "aaa";        
        unsigned char out[16];         
        AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_key); 
        AES_ctr128_encrypt( (const unsigned char *) x, out, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, &aes_key, iv, ecount, &num);
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)  printf("%02x", out[k]); // c9aa18
        printf( "\n");
        return 0;
       }
       // g++ -o aes-simple aes-simple.cpp  -I/usr/local/ssl/include  -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -g    -lcrypto
```